# Trying to Add Oracle Solaris (SunOS) OS 11.2 as a Dual Boot under Grub2

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, solaris

I was Trying to install Oracle Solaris (SunOS) 11.2 as a Dual Boot
under Grub2.
I followed the Grub2 instructions for Adding an ISO and I get the following 
Grub Entry for the Solaris ISO --

```
menuentry "Grml Rescue System (sol-11_2-text-x86.iso)" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos6'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6  fa099154-932d-47e2-a529-bf050aa7d62e
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root fa099154-932d-47e2-a529-bf050aa7d62e
    fi
    iso_path="/boot/grml/sol-11_2-text-x86.iso"
    export iso_path
    kernelopts="   "
    export kernelopts
    loopback loop "/boot/grml/sol-11_2-text-x86.iso"
    set root=(loop)
    configfile /boot/grub/loopback.cfg
```

}

But When I try booting up this Grub Entry Does "Nothing" -- This Grub
is shown in the Grub Boot-up menu ... but when I select it -- it just 
spins back to the Grub menu with nothing done to the ISO image ....
Please any one who has managed to install the Solaris ISO point me to how
to get about it ....

Comment: I don't know GRUB but I'm guessing that your scenario calls for a so-called Live CD and that doesn't seem to be what you've downloaded from Oracle. Try to use so called "Oracle Solaris 11.2 Live Media" (from the downloads page) and see if that works. Personally I've given up long time ago on the whole GRUB stuff and instead I just have a primary OS (e.g. Ubuntu) and then use VirtualBox whenever I want to run some Solaris on it. (or any other OS, e.g. Windows)

Comment: Hi @nolan6000 Many thanks for taking the time to respond. I was using GRUB as I wanted the option of Booting up More than 2 OS's including Windows, rather than go the Route of the Virtual-Box. the Virtual OS is fine ... but there is the Overhead of loading the Whole Virtual-OS from within the Real OS as compared to the Dual-Boot option where the OS is simply booted up as a fresh OS ....Also I have tried the Live-Download, am trying to load the ISO without the DVD option !!!